# Missing font text on buttons in iOS5 & iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

Last week I uploaded an app to App Store. Some of the buttons have "Telugu Sangam MN Bold 17.0" Font. It's showing fine on iOS 6 running iPhone. But on iPhone's running with iOS 5 & iOS 5.1 the button texts are blank without any text.

What exactly I need to do to solve this? Even in the simulator's of iOS 5 & iOS 5.1 the buttons are blank without text, but in iOS 6 Simulator, everything looks good.

Comment: Try using a font that is available on all versions of iOS you wish to support.

Comment: Did you copy the font to your project and set the properties in plist file(http://lawrenceleach.com/using-custom-fonts-in-ios-5)? Since it is 'Telugu' I am assuming that it is a custom font used in the app.

Answer (score 4):

I just found the solution. I set the font title as "Attributed" which is not working with iOS 5 & iOS 5.1, now I changed it to "Plain", now it's working fine all versions. Thanks Guys for reply

Comment: Thank you so much for this, been searching for hours now :)